# Блок с текстом сдвигается с центра экрана при изменении количества букв

Tags: python, html, django

только начал осваивать программирование и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
то есть при успешном заказе на сайте выдает "name Спасибо за заявку!",а во всех остальных случаях "Спасибо страница!" ,так вот дело в том,что в первом случае все работает нормально,а вот во втором (так как там меньшее количество символов) текст уезжает в сторону и никак не хочет вставать по центру,даже если задаю фиксированную длину,ширину и отступы.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block thanks %}
    <!-- Спасибо -->
    <section>
        {% if name %}
        <div class="container">
            <CENTER style = 'margin-top: 35%; margin-bottom: 35%;'><h1> {{ name }}, 
Спасибо за заявку!</h1></CENTER>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="container">
            <CENTER style = 'margin-top: 35%; margin-bottom: 35%;'><h1>Спасибо 
страница!</h1></CENTER>#
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </section>
    <!-- Спасибо -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS `text-aling: center;` для `h1` элемента.

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;"> {{ name }}, 
Спасибо за заявку!</h1>
```

Или поместите `<center>` внутрь `h1` элемента.

```
<h1><center> {{ name }}, 
Спасибо за заявку!</center></h1>
```

`h1` является блочным элементом и занимает к  тому же 100% доступной ширины, так что отцентровать его содержимое вашим способом не получится.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)